# How to get the default desktop environment while using RDP

Tags: 20.04, xrdp, rdp

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 running on a server using VMware. I installed xrdp on it, and I can RDP to the OS without issue. However, the desktop environment I get is pure Gnome and not the customized Ubuntu windows and menu bar.

Why can't I see the default Ubuntu environment? Is it because it's not supported with RDP?

Answer (score 1):

If you have performed a manual xrdp installation and no post configuration actions, this would be an expected situation.  To get the same look'n feel as your Ubuntu GNome Desktop with dock, you would need to perform some additional actions.

**Option 1 - Manual Option**

Try to create and populate the file **~/.xsessionrc** with the following content

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Please note that the .xsessionrc file is a hidden file (located in your home directory)

This would be for a **single user**. If multiple users need to perform remote connection, each user would need to have this file created in their profile

**Option 2 - Automated install**

You can also use the xrdp-installer script that basically perform the installation of the software and perform some post configuration actions that would provide you the same look'n feel when remotely connected as the one you have when connected to local console

the script and how to use it can be found [here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733)

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya

Comment: Thank you. I will try your manual option when I find time.