# Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?

Tags: remote-desktop, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and was delighted to see that a remote desktop server is built in and supports MS RDP in addition to VNC. It has some quirks related to the password, which I found out about on this post:
[22.04 - Remote Desktop Sharing authentication password changes every reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403943/22-04-remote-desktop-sharing-authentication-password-changes-every-reboot)

I am hoping to have remote desktop available on boot, without logging in, or if it uses auto-login it keeps the password, so that I can run the system headless and RDP/VNC into it. It looks like gnome-remote-desktop runs as a user service, not a system service, so it's not active unless the user logs in. And it starts before the keyring is unlocked, so it creates a new password every time it starts. It seems like there are many ways to get around these issue, but I'm not sure what's the best route or even if any/all of these are possible:

1. Continue using auto-login so that remote desktop can run as a user service but somehow fix it so that it keeps the same password (ideally without disabling keyring completely).
2. Disable the built-in remote desktop feature and install some other RDP/VNC server and manually configure it, but would that conflict with the built-in one? Not sure.
3. Is it possible to convert the gnome-remote-desktop user service to a system service? And if so, where would it store the password if not in the user keyring? Is this even an option at all?
4. Something else?!

Would love any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: If you find a workable solution, would you please post the answer?

Comment: For now, I manually setup x11vnc so get the functionality I wanted. It's not perfect, but works for now while waiting for a better solution. I'm really hoping there is a way to simply switch the built-in remote desktop feature to a system service, seems like that would make it would the way I think we all assume it should. If I find out anything more I'll share it here @BrandonMoretz

Comment: @goodkarma I am sorry my answer didn't work for you. Could you tell me in comments to my answer where it failed? Thanks

Comment: [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1409120/410225) worked for me, but as stated by the author, the default GNOME 42 UI is what is given. I was able to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283452/how-to-get-the-default-desktop-environment-while-using-rdp) to fix that problem.

Comment: check [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1419748/128903), it absolutely work.

Comment: I used to use X2Go for this, but it stopped working in 22.04 and nothing I do fixes it https://askubuntu.com/q/1432163

Comment: I think you are using the tool (desktop sharing) for the wrong job (establishing a remote Gnome session).  The whole concept of desktop sharing is that "you" have a "local" desktop, which can then be seen and interacted with by a remote "somebody".  These protocols relay window updates to the remote client, which then draws the updates there.  Remote user gestures are relayed to the local windows, which are then passed to the relevant applications.  If there is no "local", what are you sharing?

Answer (score 18):

**I have tried this solution in a VM**

> 2. Disable the built-in remote desktop feature and install some other RDP/VNC server and manually configure it, but would that conflict with
>    the built-in one? Not sure.

The solution I propose here is to not to use the native desktop sharing and use `xrdp` server instead.

## Disable the native desktop sharing (or not)

I found disabling **Remote Desktop** did not have any effect after I installed `xrdp` in the next step. After a reboot, the Remote Desktop setting reverts to look like this:

[image]

Make sure the **Enable Legacy VNC Protocol is not checked**.

**Note:** This settings page shows a randomly generated password. **Ignore it.** Use your login password when you use an `xrdp` client like Remmina in Ubuntu or Window's default RDP app

## Install `xrdp`

The setting above did not work in my fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 until I installed `xrdp`. You have to either physically access the headless computer or use `ssh` for this step.

Open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

You will be prompted to enter your password. As you enter your password the cursor will not move. This is normal.

If you have `ufw` (Uncomplicated Firewall) enabled you will have to open the port 3389 with this command:

sudo ufw allow 3389.

Verify that the `xrdp` server is up and running with this command:

```
sudo systemctl status xrdp
```

**Remember to logout**

Logging out (locally) is the most important part. If you login by physically going to the computer and connecting keyboard, mouse, monitor etc. then `xrdp` won't work until you logout.

## A Note about `xrdp` local and remote login

### Do not use Automatic login to the desktop when the computer starts!

Unlike RDP in Windows `xrdp` only works if you are **not logged in** to the remote computer **locally**. This means you physically go to the remote computer and login to it, and then leave the computer without logging out, `xrdp` will not work.

Similarly, while remotely logged in via `xrdp` you may disconnect without logging out and the session will continue. However, in this case, you won't be able to login **locally** until you log out remotely.

This is not a problem for a headless computer as you never login locally.

## Two points for the XRDP/RDP Client

### 1. Session, User and Password

When you try to access the remote computer using (X)/RDP, you may see this dialog box on your RDP/XRDP client:

[image]

1. Set Session to XOrg, the default.
2. Use your remote Ubuntu Computer's username
3. Use the remote Ubuntu computer user's login password. Do not use the randomly generated password when you set up the (x)RDP client.

You won't see this dialog if you use Remmina and choose to store your username and password with the connection configuration.

### 2. Desktop may look different

When I used Remmina to xrdp into the Ubuntu22.04 in the VM, I didn't get the default Ubuntu desktop. Instead I got the Gnome 42 desktop that looks like this:

[image]

<s>There may be some way to change it back to the Ubuntu desktop, but I didn't explore that.</s>

To change the appearance of the desktop from the default gnome to Ubuntu, create the hidden file `/home/$USER/.xsessionrc` with the following content:

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Source: [How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442514/how-to-login-to-the-ubuntu-not-gnome-session-on-a-remote-server-using-xrdp)

Thanks to [Torres](https://askubuntu.com/users/1689654/torres) and [AgentRev](https://askubuntu.com/users/858204/agentrev) for bringing this solution to my notice.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @user68186 for the detailed xdrp explanation. It's a great option. I might try that. I really like the ability to have the remote and local session be the same session, which is how it's working with xvnc, and I'm kinda getting used to it. I may try your suggestion soon and see if I adjust to it. Thanks again.

Comment: @goodkarma you are welcome. Let me know if it works for you. I understand where you are coming from. I made the same transition from vnc to xrdp a few years ago. As long as you remember to logout of local and remote sessions you will be fine.

Comment: Sometimes When I log in again using the same user. It creates multiple sessions. `loginctl list-sessions`, and at some point, a user is unable to log in unless I kill all sessions of that user, using `sudo loginctl kill-user <username>` or `sudo loginctl kill-session <session-id>`

Comment: Also, is there a way to connect to the same user every time I reconnect? Multiple people use this computer at same time and have their own accounts

Comment: @AtifAli please ask a new question with a link to this answer.

Comment: I have created a new question. https://askubuntu.com/q/1424071/376806

Comment: "There may be some way to change it back to the Ubuntu desktop, but I didn't explore that."  Has anyone else figured this out?

Comment: Looks like you can get a lot of the features by [installing Extension Manager from Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool#comment2403521_546492) and then enabling things like "Desktop Icons NG".

Comment: @endolith I haven't figured it out. Feel free to ask a new question with a link to this one  and then answer it.

Comment: this solves the Gnome/Ubuntu desktop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442514/how-to-login-to-the-ubuntu-not-gnome-session-on-a-remote-server-using-xrdp

Comment: One-liner to fix the desktop: `printf '%s\n' 'export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu' 'export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME' 'export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg' > $HOME/.xsessionrc`

Answer (score 4):

Follow by this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63uppKZ_Alk), it works.

**In short, install gnome extension :[allow-locked-remote-desktop](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4338/allow-locked-remote-desktop/) and turn on it** , and work like a charm.

If you did not hear gnome extension before, watch the video or google the term.

Comment: How on earth would "Allow locked remote desktop" help with this? Nowhere in the question  was it mentioned that they were trying to view a locked desktop?

Answer (score 3):

I found your post while looking for an answer to why Remmina works fine with the monitor or TV on but gives a black screen when the monitor/TV is off.  I’m thinking it might have something to do with the handshake communications between the viewing device and Ubuntu.  (Getting the same issue with 20.04 to a TV and 22.04 to a monitor.)

Anyway, for Auto Login I’ve done the following.  (Instructions are based on 22.04; similar for 20.04.)

**Auto Login**:

1. Settings > Users > (unlock at upper right) > Automatic Login → turn on (white dot to right)
2. Settings > Sharing →

   1. Switch at header: turn on.
   2. Remote Desktop → to on ==> the sub-menu:

      1. Remote Desktop:  on
      2. ☑  Enable legacy VNC protocol

         1. Submenu: tic ‘Require a password’
      3. Remote Control   on
      4. Authentication Section:

         1. User Name: barry
         2. Password

            - Used by Remmina to access system – 8 characters max.
            - This password is also reset by .config/autostart/password_fix.desktop (below)
   3. Media Sharing    on, plus appropriate for the sub-menu
   4. Remote Login     on, plus sub-menu allowing ssh

**Create file:**  `.config/autostart/password_fix.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Password Fix  
Comment=Corrects password in Settings > Users for use by Remmina
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 -c "import keyring;keyring.set_password('login','user','Remmina_Password');"
```

The `Exec=` is all one line. The 'user' is your user name; the 'Remmina_Password' is whatever it is being used by Remmina to log in. The legacy VNC protocol limits passwords to eight characters.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting my answer from another question, this will ensure that only the VNC/RDP password is unencrypted, everything else works with the default login keyring

> I found an insecure solution to the problem. The typical solution proposed on the internet for this is to set a blank password for the login keyring using the "Passwords and keys" app. This, however, is highly inscure as all the passwords on the device would be stored in plaintext.

> What I decided to do instead was to create a new keyring in the "Passwords and keys" app with no password and set it as the default keyring. Then I proceeded to delete the VNC password from the login keyring. Then I rebooted the computer to ensure that the new keyring is the default one. After the reboot, I reentered the VNC password in the screen sharing settings. This would store the VNC password in the new insecure keyring. Then back to "Passwords and keys" app and set the login keyring to default again. Rebooted again and now the VNC password stayed saved and the default keyring was also back to the login keyring, ensuring all foture passwords saved on the device will be encrypted.

> So in essence, I just reduced the insecurity of saving all the passwords in plaintext to storing just the VNC password in plaintext.

Comment: I have noticed though that sometimes I can't RDP into my machine (happens at random and sometimes after a reboot). I found that turning on the monitor (connected via Displayport) solves this. Haven't been able to figure out what causes this. Even considering moving back to VNC

Comment: I am trying to use Windows RDP to connect to a headless Ubuntu 22.04 machine. It works, then for some unknown reason it occasionally throws the user off (me) to the login screen. Of course rdp can't utilise this and then I'm stuck. It's a pain. Actually it is highly annoying. I wish I knew what was going on.

Answer (score -3):

Headless Chrome Remote Desktop is amazing, smooth video!
Faster than RDP on windows.
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine