# Remote desktop in 22.04 from Win 10: Authentication error

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, rdp

I mean to connect Remote Desktop from Win 10 to a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.
I can ssh.

If I am not logged into the console, I get the error

> Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these
> reasons: 
>  1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 
>  2) The
> remote computer is turned off 
>  3) The remote computer is not available
> on the network   
>  Ensure the remote computer is turned on and
> connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

If I am not logged into the console, I get the error (my translation from the Spanish message)

> Authentication error 
>   There are more data available 
>   Remote
> computer: <IP of remote>

How can I solve this?

Comment: did you install `xrdp` in Ubuntu? did you start and enable `xrdp` service? did you open port 3389 in the Ubuntu firewall? did you log out of Ubuntu before trying to access the PC remotely?

Comment: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-11-or-10/

Comment: See [this answer for Ubuntu 22.04 remote deskop headless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-deskop-headless/1409120#1409120)

Comment: Solved. I had done this many times before prior to 22.04.
But needing a quick setup I was guided by https://linuxhint.com/enable-remote-desktop-ubuntu-access-from-windows, and I thought for whatever reason `xrdp` and the rest was ready without need for me doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remote setup commands

1. sudo apt install xrdp
2. sudo systemctl status xrdp
3. sudo systemctl start xrdp
4. sudo systemctl enable xrdp
5. sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3389 proto tcp
6. ip a => [192.168.x.x from your local network]
7. RDP from Win10 [ make sure log off from Ubuntu or use another use name]
   It should work..