# multiple loginctl sessions when using xrdp

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, multi-user

I have followed this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1409120/376806 here, but I am having this issue.

Sometimes When I log in again using the same user. It creates multiple sessions. `loginctl list-sessions`, and at some point, a user is unable to log in unless I kill all sessions of that user, using `sudo loginctl kill-user <username>` or `sudo loginctl kill-session <session-id>`

Also, is there a way to connect to the same session every time a user reconnects? Multiple people use this computer at the same time and connect via Windows remote desktop utility.

Edit:
Output of `loginctl list-sessions`

```
SESSION  UID USER    SEAT  TTY  
    523 1001 ctar          pts/0
    c17 1009 user1         
    c30 1012 user2        
    c64 1004 user3          
    c71 1003 user4         
    c76 1000 user5       
    c77 1002 user6          
    c78 1002 user6          
     c8  127 gdm     seat0 tty1

9 sessions listed.
```

You can see here that there are two sessions open for user `user6` it keeps increasing and after some time I get forced disconnection when I try to connect again, the only solution is to terminate all sessions of the user then.

**Host OS**: ubuntu 22.04

**Client**: Windows Builtin and Remmina

Comment: Could you provide more details. Is the remote computer running Ubuntu 22.04? Are you using RDP from Windows or an XRDP client like Remmina (or something else)? I started a remote session using Remmina and disconnected (not logged out) and reconnected 15 times. I knew it was the same session as I had Gedit and a terminal open. Every time I reconnected one of the session's session-id kept increasing. However, the total number of sessions kept constant. Please copy the output of `loginctl list-sessions` and paste it directly in the question above. then format it by the {_} icon.

Comment: I have included the details.