# xRDP and Local Sessions

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Laptop and use xRDP to access it from my (Windows) Desktop PC. This works fine as long as I log out my session Locally otherwise I get a black screen. This means I have to log out of my laptop if I want to switch from using it locally to remotely. I'd like to have xRDP share the session with my local session to prevent having to log in and out all the time.

xrdp was installed itself via command line:
`sudo apt install xrdp`

I've seen some other solutions to this problem but they are for some earlier versions of Ubuntu and I cannot seem to get them to work.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you are using Ubuntu 22.04, add information about how you enabled xRDP in Ubuntu. In particular, did you install `xrdp` or are you using the built-in server? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426395/edit) and add these information.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've updated the question

Comment: This is a "feature" of xRDP. You may want to uninstall `xrdp` and try the built-in `gnome-remote-desktop` by enabling it in Settings. This allows both RDP protocol as well as "Legacy VNC" protocol. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-deskop-headless/1409120#1409120) for some more details.

Comment: I am testing the built in `gnome-remote-desktop` but it doesn't seem to have a option to support multiple displays that xRDP does unfortunetly it seems like one limitation or another.