# GPU stops functioning after some time

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

Sometimes after my computer is running for awhile, my GPU just stops running. In `nvtop` I can't see my GPU and only see my CPU. My CPU utilization goes through the roof as it tries to render everything (when this happened last night I could see there was some chrome render process that uses like 750% CPU in `htop`). The "Geforce RTX" light is still on when this happens. Also, my monitors are plugged in through the GPU, not the motherboard.

This wouldn't be a huge problem because restarting fixes it, but my computer is set up at home and is accessable via `ssh`. If I need to restart my computer, my GPU isn't recognized until AFTER I am signed in via the Desktop GUI. So if I'm away from home and need to reboot my computer (I do this via `sudo reboot`), I have to call my roommate and he has to walk over to my computer and sign me in. Then I can see my GPU in `nvtop` once he signs me in.

My system has a Nvidia 3080 Ti and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: This won't answer your question, but it will help you login using RDP remotely (only when you are not logged in locally). See [my answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless/1409120#1409120), You don't have to ask your friend to login for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check `dmesg` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors.

But the most likely culprit is a HW issue: either your GPU is overheating (quite common problem this generation: some GPUs were sold with incorrectly-spread thermal paste; repasting fixes it) or the PSU can't provide enough energy and it goes down after the GPU asks a power spike (transient spikes is also a common problem for the 3000 series)

## Login via CLI

In ssh you can try:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
sudo service gdm3 restart
sudo service sddm restart
```

Which one you need depends on your Desktop Manager.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the GPU to show back up by using `sudo service gdm3` Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then post the logs. There's no way a GPU disappears without nothing showing up on logs.