# Remote Desktop - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Cannot Connect

Tags: 22.04, rdp

The built in RDP connection does not allow a remote connection unless the user is already logged in.  Is there a way to configure Ubuntu 22.04 RDP so that one can log in remotely, without having already logged in on the terminal/console ?

I have installed the GNOME shell extension as well as the 'Allow Locked Remote Desktop' extension and I can lock/unlock the connection, however, I cannot log in unless I initially log in at the physical keyboard/monitor.

Comment: I'm am using remote login with 22.04, not experiencing your issues.  My system is Xubuntu so, no gnome.

Comment: Look at anything in the logs (/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log.

Comment: My notes include a comment that xrdp needs access to /etc/ssl/private/ss-cert-snakeoil.key.  Also could something about your firewall be an issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 remote desktop headless?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407444/ubuntu-22-04-remote-desktop-headless)

Comment: This feature may be added in a future version of Gnome Remote Desktop. As of now, it can be only used if you are locally logged in (but not with automatic login at startup).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It does seem odd that 'Remote' desktop does not work unless you are local (so that you can log in locally).  I will find something else to use instead.  Perhaps xrdp will not have the same issue.